# How can I identify the header that generates a warning?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm sure that many of you are familiar with this set of warnings. These are most of the time generated by a include file. Solution is `pragma push/disable/pop`, but identifying the header is not a nice task.

Does anyone knows a way of identifying the header except trial-and-error ?

```
1>File1.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\cstdio(49) : warning C4995: 'gets': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\cstdio(53) : warning C4995: 'sprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\cstdio(56) : warning C4995: 'vsprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\cstring(22) : warning C4995: 'strcat': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\cstring(23) : warning C4995: 'strcpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\cwchar(36) : warning C4995: 'swprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\cwchar(37) : warning C4995: 'vswprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\cwchar(39) : warning C4995: 'wcscat': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\cwchar(41) : warning C4995: 'wcscpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>Linking...
```

Comment: I don't quite get it. The name of the header file is in the error message...

Comment: The warning header (cstdio) is not included directly into my header. There are few "intermediary" headers that I want to find out.

Comment: I would propose to simply search for the offending functions in your project. VS keeps it indexed, so normally you should find the occurrences relatively quickly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my case, moving `#include <strsafe.h>` to the bottom of the list got rid of the warning without using extra compiler directives.

A good way to find out where `#pragma deprecated` was being called was to go into the compiler settings under "Preprocessor" and to set **Generate Preprocessed File** to something like *With Line Numbers (/P)*. Rebuild, then open up the *.i file and search for `deprecated`. Nearby will be the name of the offending include.

I'm using VS2003, so the dialogs may be slightly different for you.

Comment: The particular include gotcha in this case is that <string> needs to be included before stdio, which comes from strsafe.h.  You can look at the code and see that this has to do with some completely bizarre namespacing that VS does with the stdio functions depending on who declares them first.

Answer (score 4):

The standard include files should have include guards. So you may be able to explicitly include those files at the *top* of your own file, with that warning disabled:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4995)
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cwchar>
#pragma warning(pop)

// rest of your #includes
```

That way the warnings will be disabled for the headers where you know there are problems. This needs to be at the top of your code so the headers are included for the first time inside the warning-disabled section.

Comment: The question was not how to solve this but for an easy way of identify headers that cause the warnings (like cstdio/cstdio/cwchar in your example)

Comment: @cprogrammer: I simply used the same names shown in the error messages you quoted in the question.

Comment: @greg I was interested by the case when `cstdio`, `cstring`, `cwchar` are not included directly in my file. Suppose that I include a header named 'vector' that include the `cstdio`, `cstring`, `cwchar`. How can I identify that vector header among others ?

Comment: @cprogrammer: What I'm saying is that you don't *need* to identify `vector` in that case. If `vector` includes `cstdio` which causes a problem, then all you need to do is include `cstdio` as I described above with the relevant warning disabled. Then, later on when you include `vector`, the `cstdio` header will already have been included and will be skipped by its own include guard. So you won't get that warning a second time.

Comment: @greg `vector` cannot be modified - is written by Ms and is part of the sdk.

Comment: @cprogrammer: You don't need to modify the `vector` header. Put the lines I showed above at the top of *your* source file.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to second what @Celdecea said.

Clearly it would be nice if MS did what GCC does and specified the included path (stack?) for the file, which I presume is what you were looking for; unfortunately, I was unable to find a compiler directive to do that, so grepping through the .i file was a painful but effective replacement.

I too found that my problem stemmed from adding `#includes` after `<strsafe.h>`. Since my error list was (almost?) identical to yours I wouldn't be surprised if that also solves your problem.

If not, or if you wish to employ the `pragma push/disable/pop` style, then it seems that @Greg has the best solution in preemptively and explicitly defining those headers that are causing you pain.

Comment: `/showIncludes` compiler setting does offer the output of all #includes.

Answer (score 1):

The [notes for #include strsafe.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) include the line:

> To use the Strsafe functions inline, include the header file as shown here, following the #include statements for all other header files.

In the MSDN offline help it says:

> Important: The include line for strsafe.h should follow all other headers' include lines.

Make sure that you've only included  in cpp files and after all other c++ library header files and the warnings goes away.

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

To add to Greg Hewgill's post, I found the problem in set and I did not suspect this file.

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4995)
#include <set>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

Doing the above solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2010 (and probably other versions too) set the C++/advanced 'show includes' option to Yes or add the /showIncludes command line option.

Then compile one file at a time and search the build output window for the warning number that you're looking for and it will show the tree of include files that is generating that warning.

This technique is useful for most build problems caused by include files.

EDIT: make sure you turn off /showIncludes when the problem is fixed as it can interfere with other compiler options (e.g. /MP (Build with Multiple Processes) is disabled).

To suppress the warning add the offending include files to a 4995 suppression block as suggested by Greg Hewgill above. This can either be at the top of the source file or in a precompiled header or in a 'forced' include file included across the project (C++/Advanced/Forced Include File).

The particular problem with 4995 CRT deprecation errors is that they seem to be generated every time code calls deprecated functions even if warning 4995 was suppressed when the deprecated functions were declared.

Answer (score 0):

In my case for VS2008 these warnings were coming from `#include <vector>` (or some other `std` library.) It seems like Microsoft can't follow their own advice.

Doing the following fixed the issue:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4995)
#include <vector>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

Just make sure that you do it as early as possible in your includes.